# wordpress gutenberg validation error on save function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

so i am playing with wordpress gutenberg block dev. and already made some simple one. now i am trying to make a more complicated one of a slider.
everything works untill the save function where i get validation error and a bizzare notice about EndTag which i do not get.
this is my save function , for now i am just trying to save the slides titles. if i console log within the map, i do get what i want.

```
    save: function( props ) {
const { slides } = props.attributes; 
const id = props.attributes.id;

const displaySlides = slides.map((slide) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{slide.title}</span>
    </div>
  )
});


return (
  <div>
    {displaySlides}
  </div>
)
},
```

and here is the error i get in my dev tools:
[image]

notice that the titles are there but still i get validation error!!

what an i missing here? and what is it the EndTag thing?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Your edit function node list doesn't match up with save function node list. That's why you are getting this error. Look closely, there's a node list WP expected but it got a different node list.